# Error when trying to reindex Product Prices

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9, reindex

Hi I am getting the following error when I try to reindex product prices.

```
Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate
```

I recently had to remove an extension the prevented this. Store view pricing. I removed store id from all price tables, but no this appears. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the extension you removed created some product attributes you need to remove as well.  Check out the database table `eav_attribute` or the extension's setup scripts to figure out which one(s) it created so you can change/remove them.

```
SELECT *
FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE backend_model='catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate'
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me find the error. I accidentally missed a step in the uninstall process.